# Conditionally fill new column of data frame on column contents specified in a separate list

Tags: r

I have a dataset (x) that contains an ID column. I need to add a new dataframe column ("Var"). Var rows needs to be conditionally filled with values (0 or 1) if ID matches a list. Var rows that are not matched to a list can be left empty or with NA.

It is important for my analysis that the order of the rows is not disrupted in any way.

```r
x <- data.frame("ID" = 1:10)
list0 <- c(1,8,9)
list1 <- c(2,4,5,7,10)
```

The desired output is

```
data.frame("ID"= 1:10, "Var" = c(0,1,"NA",1,1,"NA",1,0,0,1))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
library(tidyverse)

x %>% mutate(var = case_when(
ID %in% list0 ~ 0,
ID %in% list1 ~ 1,))
```

or using `ifelse`

```
x$Var <- ifelse(x$ID %in% list0, 0, ifelse(x$ID %in% list1, 1, NA))
```

Which produces the desired output:

```
   ID var
1   1   0
2   2   1
3   3  NA
4   4   1
5   5   1
6   6  NA
7   7   1
8   8   0
9   9   0
10 10   1
```

Answer (score 1):

An option in `base R` is

```
x$var <- +(x$ID %in% c(list0, list1))
```